# Calculating altitude without refering to atmospheric pressure?

Tags: geophysics

Is the only way of calculating altitude to try to guess using the atmospheric pressure? Couldn't an electronic device analyze the force of gravity and conclude from that at what altitude it is located?

Comment: You could always drop the barometer and see how long it took to hit the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Barometric pressure is a pretty good way to measure altitude when you know the reference pressure (at sea level). This is because the rate of change of pressure is quite high: with the density of air approximately 1.2 $kg/m^3$ at sea level, a 100 m change in altitude gives you a drop of 12 g / cm^2 or 1.2% of atmospheric pressure. The "standard value" used as a rule of thumb is 30 ft/hPa - 1.08% per 100 m.

By contrast, the force of gravity scales with $1/R^2$, so when you increase height by 100 m (and the radius of the earth is approximately 6400 km), the relative change in gravitational force is

$$F_g = \frac{GMm}{r^2}\\\frac{dF}{dr} = -\frac{2GMm}{r^3} = -2\frac{F}{r}\\
\frac{\Delta F}{F} = \frac{dF}{dr}\frac{\Delta r}{F} = -\frac{200}{6.4\cdot10^6} \approx 3\cdot 10^{-5}$$

Would you rather measure something that changes 1% or 30 parts per million? I know what I prefer...

Comment: It depends on the timeframe available to do the measurement.  Weather has a large impact on your barometer, but I suppose if one integrated over weeks it would average out. But then gravity measurements are place-dependent so can't be averaged out. Do GPS calculations count?

Comment: @JonCuster - note I did say "when you know the reference pressure at sea level": that's a value that changes all the time, but it is knowable to reasonable precision (pilots adjust their altimeter settings based on up to date weather information). GPS could be quite accurate but read http://www.xcmag.com/2011/07/gps-versus-barometric-altitude-the-definitive-answer/ : a lot depends on the model your GPS uses for the earth's surface. When you can about 10's of meters, the difference is significant!

Answer (score 0):

> Is the only way of calculating altitude to try to guess using the atmospheric pressure?

Not at all. One approach is to use GPS. Older GPS receivers indicated altitude above the reference ellipsoid. More modern receivers register altitude above the geoid. The up to 100 meter difference altitude above the reference ellipsoid versus altitude above the geoid doesn't amount to a hill of beans if you are flying over a hill that is taller than a hill of beans. You need to know the local height of the terrain to know your altitude above the surface.

The best way to measure altitude is to measure altitude. Military aircraft oftentimes have radar altimeters that directly measure altitude.

> Couldn't an electronic device analyze the force of gravity and conclude from that at what altitude it is located?

No.

The first problem is the equivalence principle. One of the many consequences of the equivalence principle is that you can't measure gravity. An ideal accelerometer measures proper acceleration, the net result of all of the real forces acting on the accelerometer *except for gravitation*. (That's the Newtonian point of view of how accelerometers work. The relativistic point of view is that accelerometers measure the net real force acting on the accelerometer, period. Gravitation is not a real force in general relativity, so of course you can't measure it.)

This makes for a big problem for military aircraft and aircraft such as the Vomit Comet that by design don't fly straight and level. The aircraft's accelerometers do give a hint toward the altitude of the aircraft if you **know** the aircraft is in straight and level flight. There are however two additional problems that get in the way of using the accelerometer to indicate altitude.

The first of these additional problems is latitude. Nominal gravitation at sea level varies from 9.78033 m/s<sup>2</sup> at the equator to 9.83219 at the North Pole. At 0.3084 cm/sec<sup>2</sup> per kilometer of altitude (the [free air correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-air_gravity_anomaly)), that difference of 5.186 cm/sec<sup>2</sup> corresponds to an altitude variance of 16.82 kilometers. You need to know where you are to use your accelerometer to estimate altitude. Since you need to know where you are, you might as well just use GPS.

The next problem is gravity anomalies. Even if you know where you are, gravitation varies by ±100 mgal (±0.1 cm/sec<sup>2</sup>) compared to the nominal value for a given latitude. Suppose you fly Japan on a straight and level trajectory. While your GPS-based altimeter will show that you are indeed maintaining a steady altitude, your accelerometer-based altimeter will show you climbing over 300 meters, then dropping over 600 meters, and then climbing 300 meters to regain the initial altitude.